# Determine the highest value in a set of files

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a folder with many files in it with the file name structure like so:

```
SOP-JV-**125**-VLG-BK White Vinyl Sizes-EN-10172019
```

Each file has the - as a delimiter.

I'm writing a Sub that will create a new file for the user, based off of certain values they fill out using a form in MS Access.

How could I pull in the files and determine what the highest SOP ID (value that I made bold in the filename above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like so, using the `filesystemobject`  I haven't tested this code as yet, but will do when I get a chance.

```
Public Function GetMaxNumber(strPath As String, _
                                Optional strDelim As String = "-", _
                                Optional lngSection As Long = 2) As Long

Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Scripting.Folder
Dim fl As Scripting.File
Dim s() As String
Dim l As Long

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each fl In fld.Files
    s = Split(fl.Name, strDelim)
    l = CLng(s(lngSection))
    If l > GetMaxNumber Then GetMaxNumber = l
Next fl

End Function
```